# Failed at the mean@0.4.2 start script 'grunt'

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, mean-stack

I've been following [this mean-stack tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlVwJvE3C5A&list=PL6rhBJX0L3TWYrwrQIi1_MzQDvVhkUVPI) and got to the login-part. Everything went well until I stopped yesterday. When I try to continue my work by running npm start, I get this:

```
> mean@0.4.2 start C:\Users\Aku\mymeanproject\mean
> grunt

(node:9784) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, p
date it to a more recent version.
(node:9784) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 89 files lint free.

Running "eslint:target" (eslint) task

C:\Users\Aku\myMEANProject\mean\modules\core\client\controllers\home.client.controller.js
8:2  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
9:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
10:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
11:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
12:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
13:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
14:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
15:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
16:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
17:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
18:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
19:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
20:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
21:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
22:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
23:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
24:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
25:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
26:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
27:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
28:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
29:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
30:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
31:3  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 0  indent
32:2  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent

C:\Users\Aku\mymeanproject\mean\server.js
0:0  warning  File ignored because of your .eslintignore file. Use --no ignore to override

C:\Users\Aku\mymeanproject\mean\config\assets\cloud-foundry.js
0:0  warning  File ignored because of your .eslintignore file. Use --no-ignore to override

C:\Users\Aku\mymeanproject\mean\config\assets\default.js 
0:0  warning  File ignored because of your .eslintignore file. Use --no-ignore to override

//There 89 of these, each with a different file

✖ 114 problems (25 errors, 89 warnings)

Warning: Task "eslint:target" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"   "C:\\Users\\Aku\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\
cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mean@0.4.2 start: `grunt`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean@0.4.2 start script 'grunt'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mean package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project   with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mean
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aku\mymeanproject\mean\npm-debug.log
```

I don't even have a file called .eslintignore. Up until this everything worked great. I already updated my npm and node and that's the only change that has happened since yesterday. I'm not an expert on these things so the very few results I got from searching for this really didn't help me at all. And what about the home.client.controller.js errors? Here's the file:

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication',
  function ($scope, Authentication) {
// This provides Authentication context.
$scope.authentication = Authentication;

$scope.alerts =[
{
    icon: 'glyphicon-user',
    colour: 'btn-success',
    total: '20,408',
    description: 'TOTAL CUSTOMERS'
},
{
    icon: 'glyphicon-calendar',
    colour: 'btn-primary',
    total: '8,408',
    description: 'UPCOMING EVENTS'
},
{
    icon: 'glyphicon-edit',
    colour: 'btn-warning',
    total: '527',
    description: 'NEW CUSTOMERS IN 24H'
},
{
    icon: 'glyphicon-record',
    colour: 'btn-info',
    total: '85,000',
    description: 'EMAILS SENT'
}
];
 }
]);
```

I'm using Windows 10.

UPDATE: A new day, a new unexplained change. I don't get the eslintignore warnings anymore, but the indentation errors are still there. No matter what I do, it won't be fixed. Is this a bug?

Comment: You have incorrect indentation in that file, according to comments improve it.

Comment: No matter what I do to it, it just keeps giving errors. How can it find 0 space characters when there obviously are more?

Comment: from copy & pasted content you have many 0 spaces expressions. In other hand - try to update `eslint` package - maybe there is bug in it

Comment: Updating eslint didn't work. Can you give me an example on the indentation cause I really don't understand the issue?

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent - try to run `eslint --fix` if **eslint** is installed globaly - it will try to fix problem with indentions automaticaly

Comment: I don't know if I'm running it the right way, it doesn't seem to do anything. Is it like this: `eslint --fix home.client.controller.js` ?

Comment: Okay, it really messes up the file, it pushes things to the far right and the command prompt gives the same kind of errors as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good lord, I feel stupid. When the errors talk about space characters that's really what they are, I thought about them as tabs all this time. I blame the language barrier. :B